# When I tried to make visible the variable from an existing form in the new form it does nothing

Tags: c#, winforms

My code is :

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
   Login l = new Login();
   con.Open();
   OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [secretcode] FROM UsrDet WHERE usrname = '" + l.GetUsrName() +"';",con);
   OleDbDataReader dr = null;
   dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   while(dr.Read())
   {
      int sec = (int)dr["secretcode"];
      seccode.Visible = true;
      seccode.Text = sec.ToString();
   }
}
```

I want to cross check with the username which a user will be entering in Login form to generate a secret code and make it visible in the next form. When I clicked the linklabel in execution it does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be forgetting to *show* the `Login` form e.g.

```
Login l = new Login();
l.ShowDialog(); // block until the user closes the dialog
var userName = l.UsernameInput.Text;
// get secret code
```

However, you should try to avoid running non-UI operations like DB queries on the UI thread, mainly because you will find your UI will appear "frozen" until this code has finished. Instead you should consider firing that stuff off in a new thread thus freeing up the UI

```
var userName = l.UsernameInput.Text;
Task.Run<string>(() => 
{
    using (var con = new OleDbConnection("..."))
    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(con))
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [secretcode] FROM UsrDet WHERE usrname = @username";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userName);
        con.Open();
        using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while(dr.Read())
            {
                return dr["secretcode"].ToString();
            }   
        }
    }
}).ContinueWith((t) => 
{
    // update UI
    seccode.Visible = true;
    seccode.Text = t.Result;
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: No Login form appears first and then a new form for second step verification. When user signs in a secret code will be generated and stored in the database and for double check I want to make visible that code in next form.

Comment: @MauriousPaul well "*When I clicked the linklabel in execution it does nothing*" is what you said, maybe you should have been more specific...

Comment: Now it says System.Action is of void return type so it must not return an object.

Comment: Now it shows  The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

Comment: @MauriousPaul Should be `Task<string>.Run`. The connection error is due to you never closing your connection, I have no idea where you manage the connection because you have omitted that code therefore I didn't want to close it incase you used it elsewhere...

Comment: No I've used it only here.

Comment: @MauriousPaul see update, that's the correct way of using the connection. You shouldn't share it across threads.